# What should the limit of a function be at isolated points?

Tags: limits, functions

The limit of a real function $f$ at a real number $x$ is usually defined when $x$ is a limit point of the domain of $f$. But what should the limit of a function be at an isolated point? For example, consider a function $f$ defined only on the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. What should the limit of $f$ be at, say, $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the limit of a function at a point requires that there is a ball around that point where the function is defined. If a point is isolated then the limit does not exist at that point because there is a region around that point where the function is undefined.

In your example, let’s say $f(1)= a$ - there is no $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-a| < \epsilon$ for all $x:|x-1| < \delta$

Note that this does not apply to the limit of a sequence, so

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)$$

Can exist even if the limit of any point does not.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned yourself (and can be seen in baby Rudin's chapter 4 on continuity), the limit is only defined at limit points of the domain of the function. If the point is an isolated point, you will not be able to satisfy the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ criterion for arbitrarily small values of $\epsilon>0$, *unless* you allow $\delta=0$; but in that case, the whole definition becomes completely useless.